# How to set Privatebin/RelativeSearchPath path for current app domain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I amtrying to set PrivateBinPath to get set discovery path for private assembly.

I am trying to do that using:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = @"r:\Build";
```

But this is not getting updated. When I check following it's still null.

```
    var s2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
```

How to set it , and does not need to be during run time/